# Asyncio create background task

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have an async function:

```
async def async_function():

    async def run():

      async with MessageHandler() as eventhandler:

        instance = instance_of_smth()
        async def callback(msg: Msg):
          msg = msg.data.decode('utf-8')
          instance.add_event(msg)
      
        subject = "test"
        task = asyncio.create_task(eventhandler.subscribe(subject=subject, callback=cb))
        subscription_tasks.append(task)
        await instance.execute()

    tasks = [run()]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

And I have this MessageHandler() class (I use NATS jetstream but simplified it a bit here):

```
class MessageHandler():

  def __init__(self):
     super().__init__()
     self._nc = None
     self._js = None

  async def subscribe(subject, callback):
             self.js.subscribe(subject, cb=callback)
```

I want that subscribe to be a background task running until the instance.execute() is finished. If an message arrives from the subscription it should add this event to the instance via .add_event(). At the moment it subscribes, returns back and executes instance.execute() and there is no subscription anymore. How can I make the subscribe part a background task?